# DNS: 'A' record not updating for subdomain

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system, ubuntu-18.04, a-record, digital-ocean

I recently moved my domain from GoDaddy to DigitalOcean and the DNS records updated successfully. Then a subdomain was created on DigitalOcean called `cms.eminenceconstructionlv.com`. The NS records appear to have been assigned but not the A record. I used the `dig` command line tool to check the subdomain and there was no ANSWER SECTION in the response as expected, just an AUTHORITY SECTION with the NS records.

The DigitalOcean droplet with an IP of `142.93.203.163` is running Ubuntu 18.04 and has Nginx installed and configured as the web server.

Any ideas of what the issue is with the A record? Let me know if further info is required.

Comment: The `dig` shell command referred to above: `dig @ns1.digitalocean.com cms.eminenceconstructionlv.com`

Comment: As the author you can always [edit](https://serverfault.com/posts/1131676/edit) your own questions, which is often preferred to comments when supplying additional information.

Comment: It looks like you tried to create a subdomain by setting up NS records, which is the correct way to set up a subdomain, but usually ***only when*** it needs to be managed independently of your main domain zone. Doing that requires setting up a new zone  which is not what DNS providers typically support. Therefore in most other cases, you don't need a new zone or NS records at all. The only thing necessary to create a subdomain is to create the records you need  (A, AAAA, CNAME, MX etc)  in the existing zone.

Comment: Usually nothing  prevents you from creating something like `www.cms.eminenceconstructionlv.com` and other such records directly in the main zone.

Comment: I will eventually move the apex domain to Vercel so will need to manage them separately. [Server blocks](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04#step-5-setting-up-server-blocks-recommended) have been set up so multiple domains should not be an issue. Also I included the shell command as a comment as it was non-core info, but will avoid in the future if it's not recommended. Let me know if there's anything I can try given this info.

Comment: is it possible to share the image or the configuration ?

Comment: Actually the issue has been resolved. I removed the NS records for the subdomain and only kept the ones for the apex domain as @HBruijn suggested. That will do for now.